# Why I can't remove DB in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to remove the database called "confDB".
Look here :

```
rs0:PRIMARY> use confDB
switched to db confDB
rs0:PRIMARY> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "confDB", "ok" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin   0.203125GB
confgDB (empty)
configDB    0.203125GB
local   2.0771484375GB
test    (empty)
```

As you can see, "show dbs" still shows confDB ??!!

Comment: show dbs is not showing confDB, but there's another database name confgDB .. check the spelling again ... @Armaz

Comment: Same as above, I think it is gone

Answer (score 0):

db.dropDatabase() removes all documents leaving the database allocation intact. Therefore, as soon as new document is inserted to to the database into a collection mongod allocates a fresh location for the new documents.

to drop a database permanently issue command from terminal

> mongo  --eval "db.dropDatabase()"

Comment: "db.dropDatabase() removes all documents leaving the database allocation intact" Are you sure about that? And then you go "to drop a database permanently issue command from terminal" the exact same command

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for responding. 
I am new to MongoDb and thought I had missed something. 
I Tried it again and **now it worked**. (Maybe if some other client is using the DB, it doesn't go away ??)

It must have been a glitch or something anyway. I am sure I did it right. Here is another output I had.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin   0.203125GB
confgDB (empty)
configDB    0.203125GB
local   2.0771484375GB
test    (empty)
rs0:PRIMARY> use confDB
switched to db confDB
rs0:PRIMARY> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "confDB", "ok" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "confDB", "ok" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "confDB", "ok" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin   0.203125GB
confgDB (empty)
configDB    0.203125GB
local   2.0771484375GB
test    (empty)
```